# All combinations of N elements

Tags: c, logic

I needed help in a algorithm: I have an N number of APs (access point), and each of these APs share a channel and a frequency

channels go of 1 to X
Frequency go of 1 to Y

I need to find all the possibilities for values, So I thought in a logical like that, first do all frequency combinations, then all channel combinations, and then I collate the same.
But I'm struggling to implement this combination generator, can someone help me understand what is wrong in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main ()
{
    int j=0,key=1,cont=1,K,K2,i,AP,F;
    scanf("%d",&AP);              //Number of acess points
    scanf("%d",&F);               //Number of Frequencies
    K=pow(F,AP);                  //F^AP = Number of possibilities
    K2=K;                         //The same
    int FREQ[AP][K];              //For save the result 
    for(j=0;j<AP;j++)             //Repeat APs times
    {
        for(i=0;i<K2;i++)         //Repeat Result times
        {
            if(cont>F) cont=1;    
            FREQ[j][i] = cont;
            key++;
            if(key==K)
            {
                cont++;
                key=1;
            }
        }
        cont=key=1;
        K=K/2;
    }
}
```

for example I have 3 APs and and 2  frequencies

this for takes the number of possibilities and the frequencies of the number to set the possibilities
for example, if I have 3 APs and 2 frequencies, it will have the first run
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
in the second, as I split the F / 2
it will be
1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2

but I'm not understanding why is not working

and the output should be:

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
1 2 2
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 2 1
2 2 2
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: Btw., this is not C++ (not just bad C++ or anything, but indeed *not* C++)

Comment: @FirstStep 
the code is not returning the value that the logic should, I should be making a silly mistake that I could not understand

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it :D

```
j=0;
key = cont = 1;
K=pow(F,AP);                        
K2=K;                               
K=K/F;                              
FREQ=calloc(K2,sizeof(int*));       
for(i=0;i<K2;i++)
    FREQ[i]=calloc(AP,sizeof(int));

for(j=0;j<AP;j++)                   
{
    for(i=0;i<K2;i++,key++)
    {
        FREQ[i][j] = cont;
        if(key==K)
        {
            if(cont==F) cont=1;
            else cont++;
            key=0;
        }
    }
    cont=1;
    K=K/F;
    key=1;
}
```